# Adding more containers to a jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, containers, clock

How could i go about adding more containers to my Jframe? Heres my line of code, I would like to make a clock in one window that contains other clocks in side of the same jframe, heres my code:

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.util.Calendar;  
 public class CopyOftheclock {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame clock = new TextClockWindow();
    clock.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    clock.setVisible(true);
     }
}


 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 class TextClockWindow extends JFrame {
 private JTextField timeField;
   public TextClockWindow() {
    timeField = new JTextField(7);
    timeField.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 48));

    Container content = this.getContentPane();
    content.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    content.add(timeField); 

    this.setTitle("Norway");
    this.pack();
    javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(1000,
          new ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  String a = "";
                  Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                  int h = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    if (h==24)
                    {
                        h=8;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==1)
                    {
                        h=9;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==2)
                    {
                        h=10;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==3)
                    {
                        h=11;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==4)
                    {
                        h=12;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==5)
                    {
                        h=1;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==6)
                    {
                        h=2;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==7)
                    {
                        h=3;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==8)
                    {
                        h=4;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==9)
                    {
                        h=5;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==10)
                    {
                        h=6;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==11)
                    {
                        h=7;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==12)
                    {
                        h=8;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==13)
                    {
                        h=9;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==14)
                    {
                        h=10;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==15)
                    {
                        h=11;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==16)
                    {
                        h=12;
                        a = "P.M";
                    }
                    if (h==17)
                    {
                        h=1;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==18)
                    {
                        h=2;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==19)
                    {
                        h=3;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==20)
                    {
                        h=4;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==21)
                    {
                        h=5;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==22)
                    {
                        h=6;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                    if (h==23)
                    {
                        h=7;
                        a = "A.M";
                    }
                  int m = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                  int s = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                  timeField.setText("" + h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + a);
              }

          });
    t.start();
     }
 }
```

If you guys could help me get this to work i would really appreciate it!

Comment: heres a picture to what im trying to do http://s1173.photobucket.com/albums/r597/jackiechanwins/?action=view&current=clock.jpg

Comment: where would I put that in the code? each container is going to to have diffrent numbers in it

Comment: ive looked for methods of doing it but i havent found any at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) For displaying non-editable, text use [JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) rather than [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html).

2) For less code, use the methods of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

3) Use proper [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html); in your case (maybe) [GridLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) would let all `JComponent` have the same `Dimension` on the screen.

4) All GUI related code in the `main public static void main(String[] args) {` should be wrapped into `invokeLater()`; more in [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

5) Maybe for the rest [this thread could be useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9532796/714968).